# Blender Won't Save World Surface Shaders

Tags: world, shader-nodes, saving

I was working on a blender project, and noticed that when I opened it, all the world shaders that weren't being used got deleted.  Any Ideas on how to fix this?  Btw, I was able to restore the shaders with an autosave, but save and reloading the project still causes the world shaders to get deleted.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to click the badge next to shader name to keep it. makes a “fake user”. blender delete any thing without a user when you save.